# Setting default website redirect to virtual directory IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I have a virtual directory in IIS 7 called Foo. There is a URL that you can access at `mydomain.com/Foo/test.aspx`

I would like `mydomain.com` to automatically go to `mydomain.com/Foo/test.aspx` but can't seem to find a way to do this in IIS 7 with redirects (it keeps redirecting to `mydomain.com/Foo/test.aspx/Foo/test.aspx/Foo/test.aspx/....` if I redirect to `Foo/test.aspx` or the full address `mydomain.com/Foo/test.aspx`.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have a default document with the following content in the site root:

```
<%@ page language="c#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/foo/test.aspx");
    }    
</script>
```